# ArgumentException when trying to draw in c# Form

Tags: c#, loops, drawing, draw

First, i'm not too good known to programming (17 and still learning it), so sorry if my code isn't that good ^^

I've seen something about 2D Engine in C#, and that they're actually not that hard to code, so i wanted to give it a shot, but now i've got a problem:

I created a Panel in the Form, and then it's getting painted I "extract" the Graphics Object, and give it to my "Engine"

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Draw");
        graphics.setG(e.Graphics);
    }
```

The Engine just "saves" the Graphics object

```
    public void setG(Graphics g)
    {
        this.g = g;
    }
```

Now i've got the usual Game Loop, executing an Update and a Draw method every 1/60 Seconds, part of the draw Method:

```
        for(int i = 0;i < images.Count; i++)
        {
            var curr = images[i];
            g.DrawImage(curr.img, (int)Math.Round(curr.x), (int)Math.Round(curr.y));
        }
```

Where of course img is an Image, x and y are floats, casted to ints, now i get "unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occured in System.Drawing.dll" in the Line

```
            g.DrawImage(curr.img, (int)Math.Round(curr.x), (int)Math.Round(curr.y));
```

Exception Detail (Tried to translate a few words, original log is german):

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Invalid Parameter.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y)
       at _2D_Engine.GraphicsEngine.Draw(Graphics g) in C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\2D Engine\2D Engine\GraphicsEngine.cs:Line 38.
       at _2D_Engine.Form1.gameLoop() in C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\2D Engine\2D Engine\Form1.cs:Line 54.
       at _2D_Engine.Form1.gameLoop() in C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\2D Engine\2D Engine\Form1.cs:Line 58.
       at _2D_Engine.Form1.gameLoop() in C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\2D Engine\2D Engine\Form1.cs:Line 58.
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

This happens whatever i'm trying to draw to the Panel, also when I try to draw a Polygon for example, i get the same Exception. Not sure if I misunderstood anything about how to write the Game Loop, because it doesn't happen when i just call the draw Method from the Paint method, but the Paint Method isn't called everytime I want an object to move, so I can't use only it for the Draw Loop, i'm pretty puzzled right now ^^

Comment: Do not store and use `PaintEventArgs.Graphics` outside of the `Paint` event. Actually do all the painting only in that event. Use `Invalidate` method when you want to repaint (when you want object to move etc.)

Comment: @IvanStoev ok, i've seen a tutorial where the draw-method was called in the game-loop, but whatever... it works when i just call this.Invalidate(); in my game-loop, well kind of... it just repaints when i "use" the window, when i take it and move it on the screen for example, when it stands still, nothing happens, what did i do wrong? ^^